# Group nodes together based on condition and validate using Schematron

Tags: xslt, schematron

I am working on writing rules using Schematron to validate data below. The requirement is to verify whether a patient has at least one encounter in the past 12 months. If there are multiple encounters per patient, use the last encounter.

```
<root>
   <entry>
    <resource>
      <resourceType>Encounter</resourceType>
      <subject>
        <id>Patient/12345</id>
      </subject>
      <encounterDate>2018-04-10T10:00:00</encounterDate>
    </resource>
  </entry>
   <entry>
    <resource>
      <resourceType>Encounter</resourceType>
      <subject>
        <id>Patient/abcde</id>
      </subject>
      <encounterDate>2020-04-10T10:00:00</encounterDate>
    </resource>
  </entry>
  <entry>
   <resource>
      <resourceType>Encounter</resourceType>
      <subject>
        <id>Patient/abcde</id>
      </subject>
      <encounterDate>2019-05-10T10:00:00</encounterDate>
    </resource>
  </entry>
</root>
```

The above data should pass the validation because the latest encounter is less than a year ago.
What I want to know is, if I write a template that groups encounters together by patient id, is there a way to pass that template to the rule context? If not, is there any other way of doing it?
I am completely new to both xslt and Schematron and here is what I have so far:

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" >
   <pattern>
   <key name="patientId" match="entry" use="/resouce/subject/id/text()"/>
   <template name="dateByPatient" match="entry">
   <root>
     <for-each select="resource/subject/id">
       <patient >
         <for-each select="key('patientId',text())">
           <effectiveDateTime><value-of select="./resource/encounterDate"/></effectiveDateTime>
          </for-each>
       </patient>
     </for-each>
     </root>
   </template>
   <let name="template">
    <dateByPatient/>
   </let>
   <let name="latest">
   <root>
   <for-each select="$template/root/patient">
   <patient >
    <sort select="effectiveDateTime" order="descending" />
       <if test="position() = 1">
       <effectiveDateTime><value-of select="effectiveDateTime" /></effectiveDateTime>
       </if>
    </patient>
   </for-each>
     </root>
   </let>
     <rule context="$latest/root/patient/effectiveDateTime">
     <let name="days" value="days-from-duration(fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime(text()))" />
     <assert test="days-from-duration(fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime(text())) &lt; 365">
       Encounter date more than a year : <value-of select="$days" /> days 
     </assert>
   </rule>
 </pattern>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 3 underlying you could use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3"
    xmlns:sqf="http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/validator/process">
    <sch:ns prefix="map" uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"/>
    <sch:pattern>
        <sch:rule context="root">
            <sch:let name="groups"
                value="let $encounter-resources := entry/resource[resourceType = 'Encounter']
                       return map:merge( 
                         $encounter-resources
                         ! 
                         map { 
                           data(subject/id) : xs:dateTime(encounterDate) 
                         }, 
                         map { 'duplicates' : 'combine' }
                       )"/>
            <sch:assert 
                test="every $patient in map:keys($groups) 
                      satisfies 
                      (current-dateTime() - max($groups($patient))) 
                      lt xs:dayTimeDuration('P365D')">At least one patient with latest encounter more than a year ago.</sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

Or to output more detailed information and to only process resources with type Encounter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3"
    xmlns:sqf="http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/validator/process">
    <sch:ns prefix="map" uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"/>
    <sch:pattern>
        <sch:rule context="root">
            <sch:let name="groups"
                value="let $encounter-resources := entry/resource[resourceType = 'Encounter']
                       return map:merge( 
                         $encounter-resources 
                         ! 
                         map { 
                           data(subject/id) : xs:dateTime(encounterDate) 
                         }, 
                         map { 'duplicates' : 'combine' }
                       )"/>
            <sch:let name="failing-patients"
                value="map:keys($groups)[(current-dateTime() - max($groups(.))) gt xs:dayTimeDuration('P365D')]"/>
            <sch:report 
                test="exists($failing-patients)">Patients <sch:value-of select="$failing-patients"/> with latest encounter more than a year ago.</sch:report>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

I don't think you can mix Schematron and XSLT as freely as your code tries, you would need to set up an XProc pipeline to use `p:xslt` to group the original input and then a validation step to validate with Schematron.

As for your problems to run the second sample with node-schematron, it uses an XPath implementation that doesn't support the XPath 3.1 `sort` function it seems, node-schematron also fails to handle maps as intermediary results of a Schematron variable, so only stuffing all into one variable expression seems to do; two examples work:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3"
    xmlns:sqf="http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/validator/process">
    <sch:ns prefix="map" uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"/>
    <sch:pattern>
        <sch:rule context="root">
            <sch:let name="failing-patients"
                value="let $encounter-resources := entry/resource[resourceType = 'Encounter'],
                         $groups := map:merge( 
                         $encounter-resources
                         ! 
                         map { 
                           data(subject/id) : xs:dateTime(encounterDate) 
                         }, 
                         map { 'duplicates' : 'combine' }
                       )
                       return map:keys($groups)[(current-dateTime() - max($groups(.))) gt xs:dayTimeDuration('P365D')]"/>

            <sch:report 
                test="exists($failing-patients)">Patients <sch:value-of select="$failing-patients"/> with latest encounter more than a year ago.</sch:report>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

or

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3"
    xmlns:sqf="http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/validator/process">
    <sch:ns prefix="map" uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"/>
    <sch:pattern>
        <sch:rule context="root">
            <sch:let name="failing-patients"
                value="let 
                         $encounter-resources := entry/resource[resourceType = 'Encounter'],
                         $groups := fold-left(
                            $encounter-resources, 
                            map{}, 
                            function($m, $e) { 
                                map:put(
                                    $m, 
                                    data($e/subject/id),
                                    max((xs:dateTime($e/encounterDate), map:get($m, data($e/subject/id))))
                                )
                            })
                      return map:keys($groups)[(current-dateTime() - $groups(.)) gt xs:dayTimeDuration('P365D')]"/>
            <sch:report test="exists($failing-patients)">Patients <sch:value-of
                    select="$failing-patients"/> with latest encounter more than a year
                ago.</sch:report>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

If you need an assertion that fails then replace the `sch:report` with

```
<sch:assert 
            test="empty($failing-patients)">Patients <sch:value-of select="$failing-patients"/> with latest encounter more than a year ago.</sch:assert>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your second code but kept running to errors. The first error was about keys of map not being unique. I changed the context to "root/entry" and then I got "Function sort with arity of 1 not registered" error. I tried with fn:sort, with no luck. I then tried array:sort($groups(.)) and got "Unable to cast argument of type map(*) to type array(*) while calling sort" error.

Comment: @Hiwot, can you post a minimal example of the input that gives the error about keys of map not being unique? Also, how do you run the code? I have used oXygen XML editor 22.1 and a Schematron validation scenario.

Comment: The input is like I posted in the question. I'm running the validation with node js package node-schematron.

Comment: @Hiwot, I am sorry, it seems that the node-schematron package for XPath 3.1 support uses https://github.com/FontoXML/fontoxpath which unfortunately doesn't have all XPath 3.1 features supported, not even the `fn:sort` function.

Comment: @Hiwot, I have added an adapted version, report back whether node-schematron can work with that.

Comment: Thanks again. I got "Atomization is not supported for map(*)" error with the new version.

Comment: @Hiwot, I am sorry, but I can't invest time to work around the deficits of FontoXML XPath, I am afraid it doesn't seem to be up to the task to use the full range of XPath 3.1 with arrays and maps from within Schematron,  and is basically what all examples tried, to delegate the task of grouping and sorting to the power of maps and functions/operations on maps.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the limitations of the node-schematron package and also about culprits of using xsl with Schematron. I will write the rules in java script itself.

Comment: @Hiwot, it seems much of the trouble is with using several Schematron variables where one tries to store an XPath 3.1 map, it looks as if node-schematron then struggles with fontoxml to represent that map. When I use just one Schematron variable and store intermediary results in XPath 3.1 variables (with e.g. `let $groups := ... return`) it seems I found two examples that work with node-schematron.

Comment: The latest codes came very close to getting the expected result. What i didn't mention in the question is that there are other types of resource types other than "Encounter" but the validation is for resourceType "Encounter" only and I need to mention that in the code. So when I have "let $groups := map:merge(entry[resource/resourceType = 'Encounter'].., the result message is "Patients  with latest encounter.." and when I do rule context="root/entry[resource/resourceType ='Encounter'] and map:merge(resource.. I get two messages, one with patient id and one without. Please see edited input data

Comment: @Hiwot, I have edited the samples to use `entry/resource[resourceType = 'Encounter']` as the input for any map:merge.

Comment: Thanks again @Martin but the test passes and I see the report but the patient ids don't get displayed. The message is "Patients  with latest encounter more..."

Comment: I get `pass sample2.xml rprt  Patients Patient/12345 with latest encounter more than a year ago.` so the right patient from your sample seems to be found. As for passing versus failing, somewhere I switched from `assert` to `report` as `assert` requires you to negate the condition but you should be able to adapt that.

Comment: I tried different things but the sequence of map keys comes back as empty. What I mean is that empty($failing-patients) returns false but head($failing-patients) returns nothing, as in nothing gets displayed. exactly-one($failing-patients) does not fail but returns an empty string.

Comment: I was running the nodejs package in a react js environment. I was able to get the expected results with your code in an entirely node js application. Thank you!